# extract coefficient from auto.arima without intercept

Tags: r, time-series, coefficients

I would like to extract the AR coefficients from a few models i created with `auto.arima`. the problem is that I want to take the sum of the AR coefficients but without the intercept/mean.

```
bsp_ts <- ts(c(1,2,1,2,3,2,3,2,4,3,4,3,4,5,4,3,5,6,5,4,5,6,7,6))
bsp_auto <- auto.arima(bsp_ts, max.p = 12, max.q = 0, seasonal = FALSE, d=0)
summary(bsp_auto)
sum(coef(bsp_auto))
```

how can I access only the AR coefficients? I know the coefficients are saved in a list from `auto.arima`, thus I think the solutions is to access the coefficients with the corresponding "list language", but I'm still unexperienced with lists. Can anybody help? :) thanks in advance...

**Edit: Multiple models**

```
bsp1_ts <- ts(c(1,2,1,2,3,2,3,2,4,3,4,3,4,5,4,3,5,6,5,4,5,6,7,6))
bsp2_ts <- ts(c(1,2,1,2,3,2,3,2,4,3,4,3,4,5,4,3,5,6,5,4,5,6,7,6))
bsp3_ts <- ts(c(1,2,1,2,3,2,3,2,4,3,4,3,4,5,4,3,5,6,5,4,5,6,7,6))

bsp_ts <- list(bsp1_ts, bsp2_ts, bsp3_ts) 

bsp_auto <- lapply(bsp_ts, function(x) auto.arima(x, max.p = 12, max.q = 0, seasonal = FALSE, d=0))
```

coefficient extraction for multiple models, something like this:

```
ARcoef_li <- lapply(ARpers_li, function(x) sum(ARpers_li$x$coef)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Single Model**

```
library(forecast)
bsp_ts <- ts(c(1,2,1,2,3,2,3,2,4,3,4,3,4,5,4,3,5,6,5,4,5,6,7,6))
bsp_auto <- auto.arima(bsp_ts, max.p = 12, max.q = 0, seasonal = FALSE, d=0)
```

You can do:

```
my_coefficients = bsp_auto$coef
my_coefficients[!names(my_coefficients) == 'intercept']
```

Note that when you type `bsp_auto$`, RStudio will give you suggestions on the avavailable objects to extract from the model. That information can maybe help you in the future with similar tasks. `bsp_auto$coef` returns a named vector:

```
      ar1 intercept 
0.7877316 3.6909753
```

so the second line in my answer is used to 'discard' the `intercept` from our vector.

Hope this helps!

---

**Multiple models**

```
bsp1_ts <- ts(c(1,2,1,2,3,2,3,2,4,3,4,3,4,5,4,3,5,6,5,4,5,6,7,6))
bsp2_ts <- ts(c(1,2,1,2,3,2,3,2,4,3,4,3,4,5,4,3,5,6,5,4,5,6,7,6))
bsp3_ts <- ts(c(1,2,1,2,3,2,3,2,4,3,4,3,4,5,4,3,5,6,5,4,5,6,7,6))

bsp_ts <- list(bsp1_ts, bsp2_ts, bsp3_ts) 

bsp_auto <- lapply(bsp_ts, function(x) auto.arima(x, max.p = 12, max.q = 0, seasonal = FALSE, d=0))

lapply(bsp_auto,function(x){ x$coef[!names(x$coef)=='intercept']} )
```

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot! now i want to do this for all my models.. i edited my question for a cleaner presentation. I am searching now for sth like this: `ARcoef_li <- lapply(ARpers_li, function(x) sum(ARpers_li$x$coef))`

Comment: Please do not change your question after it has been answered, since any answers already posted will be wrong all of a sudden. Instead consider framing it as a new question on Stack Overflow along with your new insights and attempts. Any way, I have added a line of code that should help you extract the coefficient from multiple models, hope this helps!

Comment: thanks! it worked and in the future i will post a new quesstion :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!